# Joomla Site URL

Tags: url, joomla, dns

I have a website on a 1and1 server. I have 2 domains on the package; the default url somenumbers.websitehome.co.uk and my actual URL.

The problem is, Joomla quotes the somoenumbers.websitehome.co.uk in system e-mails instead of my actual URL. They both point to the same directory I just don't want to give a stupid URL to my users.

I think I have narrowed it down to the $siteUrl variable but I'm not sure how to go from here.

Thanks

James

Comment: quotes that other domain how? in headers? in the text? also, consider permanent redirect via `htaccess` from your subdomain to main url

Comment: So in emails it says "To access your account, please visit somenumbers.websitehome.co.uk but not my domain. The code for the mail message shows %s for the link. The my domain does point to the correct place, just Joomla pulls the wrong url

Comment: and what triggers email sending? registering new account via backend or?

Comment: Yes the e-mail comes when a new user registers, whether backend or frontend

Comment: are you sure that the user didn't acccess using the default hosting url? why not setting htaccess redirect which makes sure user is on the right domain, and then see if the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this sounded largely like a DNS issue - but then you said you only have 1 Joomla installation and both domains point to that directory.

If they're both pointing to the same directory, then both domains will display the same Joomla installation.  That is, unless you're checking to see where they are coming from and having the content display dynamically based upon how they got to your site - but from your comments I doubt you're doing that.  How your domains are behaving is the expected response if you're pointing them both to the same directory.

If you want 2 sites on the same hosting?  Setup 2 databases (or apply different prefix for each site and use 1 database) and set up each website in it's own directory.

Adjust the DNS of each domain name (and subdomain name) to point the appropriate directory.

From there, use the .htaccess file and SEF URL's to get rid of any indicator of the directory so that it displays the same as if the site was in the root directory.

That is the best way to accomplish what you're after - because from the sounds of it Joomla is doing exactly as it should, displaying correctly what is in the directory since both domain names point to the same directory.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the issue. He does not need or have two sites. First domain is generated by the hosting provider which you can use to access `public_html` even without having a domain name

Comment: I effectively just want my base URL to be my domain, not the hosting provider generated url

Comment: you just have your hosting through 1and1 right?  So at some point you had to create the domain name to point there via DNS correct?  Or was this an automatic setup of joomla through c-panel or something?  check the $live_site variable in configuration.php - clean it out.  Double check your DNS for your domain name to ensure it's pointing at your root directory.

Comment: Yes I am with 1and1. I set up Joomla manually but in a sub-folder of the root directory. I pointed the domain to the sub-folder. Should I have installed Joomla in my root folder?

Comment: No, you can do it by setting it up in a directory without issue.  Where did the domain name somenumbers.yourdomain.uk.com come from then?  It had to be created somewhere along the line, most likely as a subdomain - did 1and1 do that?  I haven't heard of hosting providers doing such a thing - but maybe they're different?

Answer (score 0):

$siteUrl should be left blank.

Comment: I don't even know where $siteUrl is initiated so haven't changed it.

Comment: In the directory Joomla is installed in, look in configuration.php